# Smartgit: Graph readability

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, smartgit

I like Smartgit more that Sourcetree. But when comparing the commit graphs I must say the one from Sourcetree looks much nicer.
Is there a way to change modify the graph generation of Smartgit to make it look like the one from Sourcetree?

The left picture shows my repository graph in Sourcetree, the right picture shows the same repository in Samrtgit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think SmartGit visualisation is not optimized to show the whole "all branches" history, as SourceTree is.

My personal preference in SmartGit is to check the "first-parent" option, which renders a linear history, with all merge commits showing a little "+" icon that you can dynamically expand to explore the history that you choose.

In this mode, SmartGit visualisation shines over SourceTree (to my taste, of course this is very subjective) — together with the ability to check only what branches you're interested in the branches panel. By contrast, SourceTree has only two modes: either all branches, of the current branch (so to visualize one branch history you have to make it current, which is often not necessary).

Also, one of SmartGit's choice that makes sense to me is to limit the overall width of history lines to the left, and use navigation arrows that you can click on to follow a specific history line. On big graphs with a lot of branches selected for viewing, this can be confusing compared to SourceTree's neater graph. But I think the aim is to make targeted navigation easier, which I need more often than a "general picture" examination.

To make it short, I think that SmartGit and SourceTree have made different visualisation choices, and they shine in different situations.